# print multiple links for a variable in PHP

Tags: php, variables, hyperlink

How can I give multiple links on the variable getting through MYSQL. In below link username is getting common link. I want to use respective link for individual username.

e.g.
http://www.bahrainmedicalbulletin.com/output2.php

PHP Script

```
  <html>
    <body>
    <?php
    $username="username";
    $password="password";
    $database="database";
    $localhost = "localhost";

    mysql_connect($localhost,$username,$password);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
    $query="SELECT * FROM people";
    $result=mysql_query($query);

    $num=mysql_numrows($result);

    mysql_close();
    ?>
    <table border="1" bordercolor="#000000" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">ID</font></td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Full Name</font></td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Telephone</font></td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Birthday</font></td>
    </tr>

<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"name");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"telephone");
$f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"birtday");

?>

<tr>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">**<?php echo "<a href=\"riz_ritz.png\">{$f2}</a>"; ?>**</font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f4; ?></font></td>
</tr>

<?php
$i++;
}
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"link");
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo "<a href='http://www.yoursite.com/".$f5."'>{$f2}</a>"; ?></font></td>
```